# Running migrations from my django server not updating django_migrations table

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a django server and I run a lot of migrations now and then. However, sometimes my migrations are run correctly and completely but the django_migrations table does not get updated.
I had run the following commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Followed by:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

What could be the reason for this? django_migrations table still shows the previous migration and new one did not get added.

Comment: Have you used these commands `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: After `python manage.py makemigrations` only you will be able to see that your changes in models got reflect or not.

Comment: I have run both the commands and they work correctly. But after migration, the table remains un-updated.

Comment: It's suggestion if you don't have an important data in database then comments all models in models.py and comment all urls in urls.py and run both commands and then uncomment  the previously commented code and run both commands again.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure out what's causing this? I've come across a similar issue.